# Partition/Volume grayed out but full read/write access

Tags: finder, hard-drive, partition, permission

i have a Mac Server and a partition only for files. The volume is grayed out in the Finder sidebar, but if i go to the folder via CMD + G (go to folder) and type "/Volumes/Server_Daten" the volume opens and i can read and write. If i go to informations (CMD + ALT + I) i can't change the permissions (little lock symbol is grayed out too).

I have the root user enabled, but even as root i can't change the permissions and have to go to the folder via CMD + G.

How can i fix the grayed out volume in the sidebar?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

The partition was hidden (i don't know why...) so i made it visible again:

```
chflags nohidden /Volumes/MY_PARTITION
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. You wouldn't believe the fixes some of the mac forums are proposing for this...